# HTTP request over IPv6

Tags: http, header, ipv6

I want to know the difference between the header format of HTTP `GET` request that uses from IPv4 server to IPv6 server?

Now, currently I am using the following format:

```
"GET /"+myFileToDownLoad+" HTTP/1.1\r\n"+
            "Accept: image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, application/x-shockwave-flash, */*\r\n"
            +"Referer: http://"+myDstIp+"/\r\n"
            +"Accept-Language: he\r\n"
            +"Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n"
            +"User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)\r\n"
            //+"Host: "+myDstIp+"\r\n"
            +"Host: "+((myHost==null)?myDstIp:myHost)+"\r\n"
            +"Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
```

So, if i want to use the IPv6 server, is it necessary to change the format?

Answer (score 7):

RFC 2732 updates the Host field:

> The following changes to the syntax in RFC 2396 are made:    (1)
>   change the 'host' non-terminal to add an IPv6 option:
>
> ```
>   host          = hostname | IPv4address | IPv6reference
>   ipv6reference = "[" IPv6address "]"
> ```
>
> where IPv6address is defined as in RFC2373 [ARCH].

So you should enclose IPv6 address in square brackets.

**Update:** 
The change applies to URLs with host part in IPv6 format and propagates to all request fields that use 'host' part from the original address - in your example these are Host and Referrer.
That is, you'll have to add square brackets around `myDstIp` in `Referrer` and `Host` fields.

Comment: @ramuluponnam: For your code it may look like:
`if (isIPv6(myDstIp)) myDstIp = '['+myDstIp+']'`

Comment: Hi Lyth,  this might be in url specification.i am asking in http request header.In that header where it could reflect.

Comment: thanks for your response. May i know where it is reflected in the request header.
i think this is thr url part. i am opening the url by providing htp://[ipv6adress]:port
it is working fine. But i am making a http request to that server from linux machine . i want to know the difference in that request format. Can you please update this? i need this information.

Comment: @ramuluponnam "Referrer" and "Host" fields are both affected by the changes, because they are based on the requested URL.

Comment: +"Referer: http://"+myDstIp+"/\r\n"
+"Host: "+((myHost==null)?myDstIp:myHost)+"\r\n"

Comment: Hi Lyth,                                                           Thanks for your help.                                          +"Referer: http://"+myDstIp+"/\r\n"         is this enough to change in my code.can you please confirm if any thing needed.                                                              thanks in advance.

Comment: You're on the right track - the only fields you need to change are Host and Referrer. I've updated the answer, hope that makes it more clear.

Comment: Thanks Lyth.that helped me alot.                                      if you dont mind can you ping the ftp request headers with using ipv4 address and ipv6 address?

Comment: Sorry, but you'd better refer to yet another [RFC 2428](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2428), this discussion has grown past the limits of the question.

Answer (score 1):

*RFC2396 Uniform Resource Identifiers (URI): Generic Syntax* was updated by *RFC2732 Format for Literal IPv6 Addresses in URL's*.

Specifically, section 3 in RFC2732.