# Why would IPv6 interfere with a Web Deploy?

Tags: visual-studio, iis, teamcity, msdeploy

Why would a Visual Studio Web Deploy have a failure of "unexpected error occurred on a send" when publishing to an intranet site that resolves as an IPv6 address? I am assuming IPv6 had something to do with it because adding the IPv4 address to the hosts file resolves the issue and the web deploy succeeds.

Details:

- Initially the build error came from a TeamCity build agent, but the same issue occurs when attempting to publish (or just validate the connection in the publish profile) from Visual Studio.
- A ping (successful) to the target machine resolves to an IPv6 address which is identical to the address found from running "ipconfig" on the target machine itself, except for a different Scope ID on the tail end.
- Windows UNC share paths to the target machines work fine
- The target machine is actually the host of the VM on which the build agent runs.

Below is the error from validating connection on publish profile.

[image: Error message from Validate on publish profile]

And detail from the original build/deploy attempt.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4276, 5): Web deployment task failed. (Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'https://tapserver:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=MealPlannerCIAPI'.)
>   This error indicates that you cannot connect to the server. Make sure the service URL is correct, firewall and network settings on this computer and on the server computer are configured properly, and the appropriate services have been started on the server.
>   Error details:
>   Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'https://tapserver:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=MealPlannerCIAPI'.
>   The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
>   Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>   An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Again I've fixed the issue, but it is a very baffling fix to me. What would break any of the msdeploy calls that is fixed by adding the IPv4 address to the hosts file when it is clearly already reaching that host using v6?

Comment: because not only do your machine and the server have to be capable of ipv6, all the routers between you and the server have to be as well.  if there isn't an appropriate service that does v6->v4->v6 bridging between you and the server, your packets will simply get lost somewhere. e.g. there may be a 10 lane superhighway from your house to the edge of town, and another 10 lane highway from the edge of the server's town to its front door, but your cities are separated by an ocean and a muddy goat path.

Comment: Ah, and that applies even without internet involved? This is strictly all on the same LAN, from a VM to its host [though yes I'm sure it has to hit the router so maybe that's enough]. It's just surprising that it would fail when ping, share paths, and access to existing web endpoints on that machine all work. Just not these msdeploy calls on port 8172. Heck even if I paste the msdeploy endpoint into a browser I can see that the endpoint is *there*...

Comment: if it's all local, and you don't need ipv6, could just try turning off ipv6 on both ends.

Comment: Yeah, putting an ipv4 address in hosts file bypassed the issue but turning off ipv6 in general sounds like a good solution to bypass it going forward. I'm starting to wonder if it could even be a bug in how the http calls are made in MS's web publishing code - maybe they're just not written for IPv6 (based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7468782/http-request-over-ipv6)

Comment: Have you checked whether the IPv6 based messages (HTTPS of course) ever arrive on your server? Even if they arrived, there could be firewall rules to block, or your IIS Management Services simply only monitor IPv4 address. There are still a lot to investigate before giving up.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Option `IP Address Restrictions` in the Management Service-Configuration (IIS)?

Please be aware that you're always connecting with your local IPv6 address if you try to access an IPv6 target. If you have configured any restrictions, they won't apply for your IPv6 address as the restriction configuration is not compatible with IPv6. So your connection attempt will be declined automatically if you set `Access for unspecified clients` to `Deny`.